# PegKit: Grammar syntax which handles same work in different ways

Tags: ios, syntax, pegkit

I'm working on some code which uses [PegKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) and I've hit something I'm not sure how to figure out. I have a syntax that looks like this (simplified):

```
expr = runtimeExpr | objectExpr;
runtimeExpr = is? runtimeObject;
objectExpr = runtimeObject keyPath;
runtimeObject = '[' string ']';
is = 'is';
keyPath = string;
```

I'm looking for the following results:

```
[abc] -> runtime expr.
is [abc] -> runtime expr.
[abc].def -> object expr.
```

However what is occurring is the generated parser code looks like this:

```
if ([self predicts:STLOGEXPRESSIONPARSER_TOKEN_KIND_IS, 0]) {
    [self runtimeExpr_]; 
} else if ([self predicts:STLOGEXPRESSIONPARSER_TOKEN_KIND_OPEN_BRACKET, 0]) {
    [self objectExpr_]; 
}
```

Which effective says that in order to parse a runtime expr, it has to start with 'is'. Which means that `[abc]` is being passed as a object expr instead.

So what i need help with is understanding how to express this logic in the grammar syntax:

1. If the string starts with a 'is', followed by a runtimeObject, or is only an runtimeObject, then process it as a runtimeExpr.
2. Otherwise process it as an objectExpr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

I believe the problem here is the leading optional `is?`. Any rule that begins with an optional prefix like this, and then subsequently matches something similar or identical to another rule (`runtimeObject` in this case) can cause problems.

But the solution is easy. Just reorder things a bit. PEGKit is **deterministic** which means it will try the **OR** alternatives in the order you specify in the grammar. So in this case just place the **longer** alternative rule (`objectExpr`) **first** (before `runtimeExpr` in the `expr` rule).

Try this, I believe everything will work out:

```
expr = objectExpr | runtimeExpr;
objectExpr = runtimeObject keyPath;
runtimeExpr = is runtimeObject | runtimeObject;
runtimeObject = '[' string ']';
is = 'is';
keyPath = string;
```

Note the changes I made to both the `expr` and `runtimeExpr` rules. I suspect only the change to `expr` is necessary to solve this problem, but the change to `runtimeExpr` is harmless. Experimentation should tell you whether the `runtimeExpr` change is actually necessary.

Comment: Ahh. I've used the deterministic aspect in other parts of the grammar. I had just the runtime first because I thought it would be a better idea to check it first. I ended up getting around this a different way. I realised that my grammar wanted different code on 'is runtime' as opposed to 'runtime ...'. So I was able to shift things around. However I like your suggestion and I think it may allow me to simplify the overall grammar. Thanks Todd.

Comment: P.S> As a general question. Is it a better idea to use the returns token array from a parse, or to use the callbacks as tokens are parsed? Currently I'm pretty much ignore the returned array of tokens and using the callbacks to pop and process tokens as they are generated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the latter (callbacks) is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Todd. Had this nagging doubt in the back of my mind that I might have taken as less than ideal path to solving my problem :-)